# sending a function instance over API (django)

Tags: python, function, instance, django-apps

maybe a stupid question :)
I have two Django apps,
I need one of them to use the functions of the other one without importing them.
as if I am requesting them using API, is there a way I can get an instance of a function and use it, I don't want to do the following:

```
response = requests.get('HTTP://URL/example/', data)
data = response.json()
```

I want instead to do something like this

```
function = requests.get('HTTP://URL/example/')
```

and execute the function as follows

```
data = function()
```

thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what higher level problem you are trying to solve? Because I am getting that [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) itch.

Comment: I have an app that has the connection with the database 
I want the other to have these privileges too

Comment: just by using the same functions at the first one

Comment: You can of course define a module that `def`ines a function that returns the data from the request and use that in your code. But that's surely not your question, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `marshal` module to serialize function code, add it as a request content and deserialize in the other app.

```
In [13]: def foo(a, b):
   print a + b
  ....:

In [14]: import marshal

In [15]: a = marshal.dumps(foo.func_code)

In [16]: a

Out[16]:
'c\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00|\x01\x00\x17GHd\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00at\x01\x00\x00\x00b(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x1f\x00\x00\x00<ipython-input-13-a0f238eac2f8>t\x03\x00\x00\x00foo\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

Another interpreter:

```
In [13]: import marshal, types

In [14]: a = marshal.loads('c\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\r\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00|\x01\x00\x17GHd\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00at\x01\x00\x00\x00b(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x1e\x00\x00\x00<ipython-input-1-a0f238eac2f8>t\x03\x00\x00\x00foo\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')

In [15]: types.FunctionType(a, globals(), 'foo')(1, 2)
3
```

However you need to ensure that no one will send you malicious code before executing it. Also please note that you will not have access to any global variables which where defined in original module of the function.

Generally I would not recommend this approach. Better to just use RestAPI to get results you want instead of passing functions around.